# Call MapboxDirections() multiple times inside loop

Tags: mapbox

I have been working with Mapbox Direction API and I am getting more than 100 of waypoints. As per Mapbox documentation I can't request more than 25 of WP to get a route, So I am calling it inside a loop of array with 25 WP chunk. Below is my sample code:

```
    componentDidMount(waypoints) {
        let wpChunks = this.chunkArray(waypoints, 25);

        for (let chunk of wpChunks) {
            routeArr.push(await this.callDirectionApi(chunk));
        }
        console.log('routeArr : ', routeArr);
    }

    callDirectionApi = (waypoints) => {
        let directions;
        directions = new MapboxDirections({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            unit: 'metric',
            profile: 'mapbox/driving',
            interactive: false,
            controls: false,
            proximity: [88.30, 22.58]
        });

        this.map.on('load', (e) => {
            let wpIndex = 0;
            for (let ii = 0; ii <= waypoints.length-2; ii++) {
                if (ii == 0) {
                    directions.setOrigin(waypoints[ii]);
                } else {
                    directions.addWaypoint(wpIndex, waypoints[ii]);
                    wpIndex++;
                }
            }
            directions.setDestination(waypoints[waypoints.length-1]);

            directions.on('route', function(e) {
                **console.log('Routes: ', e.route);**
                resolve(e.route[0].geometry);
            });

            this.map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');
        });
    }
```

As a result, if I console.log the route output(the above bold line), I am getting same route as a response in each request inside loop.

Can anyone suggest me please am I doing anything wrong or not? Is this the right way to do so? If no, can you suggest any sample example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the JS library doesn't work well with parallel requests. You should either adapt the code to make the requests one after another, or call the REST API directly.